# Best Practice for laying out UI Programmatically for both iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, constraints

Looking for a clean solution to laying out UI programmatically and having it look right on every device.  I've tried extending CGFloat to scale numbers depending on the device

```
extension CGFloat {
    func scale() {
        // Modifies self by multiplies by the ratio between the initial screen size and the desired screen size
    }
}

// usage
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.scale())
```

I've also tried just creating two different sets of constraints for iPhone and iPad and activating them depending on which device the app is being run on, but this seems unnecessarily verbose.

How can I layout my UI so that it will work on all devices without hacky workarounds.  Are there certain types of constraints I should be avoiding? (for example, instead of setting width/height constants, set them to a multiple of the screen's (or some other view's) width/height?)

EDIT:  I don't want to over-explain my own situation, so let me re-ask the question.  What are some best practices for setting constraints in an application designed for both iPhone and iPad.  Is it bad practice to just check if the device is an iPad, and if it is, have constraints just for iPad, and, if not, have constraints for just iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to just check if the device is an iPad, and if it
>   is, have constraints just for iPad, and, if not, have constraints for
>   just iPhone.

If you're planning for Split-View support, that is definitely a no-go. The code for achieving and handling this is always going to be slightly verbose. There are no one-liners here to achieve what you want.

In your `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` method, you'd want to setup your views with the base trait collection available to the controller's view. This is your starting point.

As and when your App's windows are resized by the OS (imagine going for a fullscreen app in landscape mode to a split-sized app, occupying one-third of the screen): the `-[UIViewController traitCollectionDidChange:]` method is called on your View Controller. This is where you update your layout constraints.

You can, and should, encapsulate your layout logic in a single method and call it from `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` as well as `-[UIViewController traitCollectionDidChange:]`.

In such a method, I do not recommend checking if the host device is an iPad. You specifically want to look at the active trait collection's `horizontalSizeClass` & `verticalSizeClass` properties to determine the values for your layout constraints.

For further information, I suggest you go through the following documentation:
 1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection?language=objc
 2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange?language=objc

The 2nd link has a simple example on how to check if you need to update your constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Your question, as-is, cannot be answered...

Wha does your app do? If it's a photo slide-show, constrain an imageView to the full view and set its content mode to scale-fit. Voila! It "looks good" on all devices!

If your app is more complex than that, you will likely need to make use of ***all*** the types of constraints: elements relative to each other; equal to each other; relative/equal with constant adjustments; relative/equal with multiplier adjustments; etc. And you may want different layouts (not just different sizing) based on device+orientation, in which case you'll also want to take advantage of size-class-variations.

In addition, getting an app to *"look right on every device"* involves much, *much*, ***MUCH*** more than applying constraints.

- Should the app use a Tab Bar?
- A Navigation Bar?
- A combination of them?
- Neither?
- Should it use text-buttons or image-buttons?
- Should it adjust for accessibility and dynamic fonts?
- Might it even have different functionality when running on a small screen vs a large screen?

In general, your first step should be hand-drawing every screen and UI element you expect to have - including the activity "flow" - with variations for sizes and orientations, so you are designing the best UI/UX from the beginning. At that point, you begin actual UI construction.

Keep in mind, there are people who can't produce a "Hellow World" app but make a ***very good*** living as "App Designers."

Having said all that, though... one approach you almost *certainly* should not take is:

```
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.scale())
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is a quick example - based on this article: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started

A simple weather app - constraints set so it looks similar on all iPhone and iPad models:

[image]

[image]

But, what happens when you rotate the phone?

[image]

Little, tiny cloud doesn't look so good. Add trait-variations / size-classes, and we can get:

[image]

---

And, to try and answer your edited question of: *"Is it bad practice to just check if the device is an iPad..."*?

Yes. It's recommended to design for trait-variations / size-classes so your app will look the way you want in all configurations (hopefully future-proof for the next device that comes out as well).

Comment: My answer remains the same. If you want your app to "look good" on all devices - including orientation and iPad multi-tasking - you have to ***design*** your app to look good for different sizes, and ***then*** start laying out your UI and constraining your elements.

Comment: The app has been fully designed.  I have screens for both iPad and iPhone, but they look identical other than some sizing.  Should I be creating two completely different sets of constraints for iPhone and iPad, or one set that fits both.

Comment: Is your app restricted to Portrait Orientation only?

Comment: It's landscape only

Comment: How do I set size-classes trait-variations without storyboards?

Comment: You would likely create arrays of constraints and then activate / deactivate them as appropriate in response to `traitCollectionDidChange`

Answer (score 0):

I usually first get the size of the screen and then use percentages of the width/height for the frames

```
height = view.bounds.height
width = view.bounds.width
mybutton.frame = CGRect(x: width * 0.05, y: height * 0.02, width: width * 0.3, height: height * 0.1)
```

Comment: I feel like setting the frame as opposed to using auto-layout is a bad idea in terms of stability and longevity